# JSP cannot evaluate array index properly

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, el

For a simple webapp, I'm trying to print value of ArrayList on jsp side is highly unintuitive. I'm having a hard time piecing this thing together.

This is a Spring Boot application and the following is what I send for a response --

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
    List<APojo> lis = new ArrayList<>();
    APojo po = new APojo();
    po.setName("Apple");
    po.setName("Ball");
    lis.add(po);
    model.put("fruits", lis);
    return "index";
}
```

The index.jsp page --

```
<html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Title goes here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:set var = "fruitVal" value = "${fruits[0].name}"/>
    <h2>Value: ${fruitVal}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect it to display Apple, but it keeps printing Ball. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add 2 objects to list (or remove `po.setName("Ball");`) :

```
APojo po = new APojo();
po.setName("Apple");
lis.add(po);
po = new APojo();
po.setName("Ball");
lis.add(po);
```

Consider also using a constructor that accept name

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I see my issue now. When trying to post here, I ended up overriding the same field for that object. Was skeptical of asking here but based on how quick I got a reply, now am motivated to help others here myself.